# Drag with speed in Unity game not equal depending on resolution

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, screen-resolution

I'm doing a game in Unity, it is a space shooter and I had made a script for moving my spaceship. This game is developed for Android devices, and I'm moving the ship with the Touch. It is something like dragging the ship, to the position you want. Also one must note, that I'm not considering if you touch in the center of the ship in order to drag it.
However I'm having problems, depending on the device where I'm working, the ship is not following correctly the drag, for instance if I'm on a tablet, if I move with the finger, let's say 3 inches, my ship is only moving one. However, on my mobile device it is working fine.

What I'm doing wrong? I attach you the code for the movement:

```
void MovePlayer (Vector3 movement)
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = movement;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position = new Vector3 
        (Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 
         0.0f, 
         Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax));
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().rotation = Quaternion.Euler 
        (0.0f, 
         0.0f, 
         GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x * -tilt);
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;

        float moveHorizontal = touchDeltaPosition.x;
        float moveVertical = touchDeltaPosition.y;

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical) * speedMouse;
        MovePlayer (movement);
    }
}
```

Lot of thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: Just a random thought but since the resolution between androids and tablet are different so I imagine while your current setup works for android, your speed values may need to be changed for tablet. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are using a `speedMouse` variable. Speed should have absolutely nothing to do with this, and would be the exact reason for your problem. You should be moving objects based solely on position of touch/mouse. not with speed. because speed is the only thing that will differ your output from cross resolutions.

Think about it this way, if your speed is 10 pixels/second you will move a lot slower on a denser screen, however if you are only updating position based on location on the screen, speeds will never differ.

Comment: I understand, It seems completely right what you are saying. However, I want to use the speed because I don't want to move automatically the plane to the selected position. I want the the plane to go there, not to appear in the point where I tap. Do you know what can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can do a `if (Screen.dpi > 0) speedMouse *= Screen.dpi` but keep in mind that physical screen size can be hard to calculate sometimes and if Unity cannot determine screen size then `Screen.dpi` will return `0`

Answer (score 8):

Touch `position` and `deltaPosition` are in pixels, so you can't assume that results will be consistent across varying resolutions.

There are a few ways you can mitigate that, depending on your design needs...

You could express the touch `deltaPosition` as a fraction of the screen resolution:

```
float screenSize = Mathf.Max(Screen.width, Screen.height);
Vector2 touchDeltaPosition  = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
Vector2 touchDeltaPercentage = touchDeltaPosition / screenSize;

//touchDeltaPercentage values will now range from 0 to 1
//you can use that as you see fit
```

You could use the main camera to transform screen coordinates into world positions, then check the difference between those:

```
Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

Vector3 screenCenter = new Vector3(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f, 1f);
Vector3 screenTouch = screenCenter + new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, touchDeltaPosition.y, 0f);

Vector3 worldCenterPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenCenter);
Vector3 worldTouchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenTouch);

Vector3 worldDeltaPosition = worldTouchPosition - worldCenterPosition;

//worldDeltaPosition now expresses the touchDelta in world-space units
//you can use that as you see fit
```

The point, with either method, is that you want some units that aren't tied to screen resolution.

Similar to the above, you could also use the main camera to raycast against terrain, or a large plane, or some other collider(s) in the scene.